# If $ f(x)= x\int_2^{x^2} \sin(t^3)dt$, then $f'(x)=?$

Tags: integration

If $ f(x)= x\int_2^{x^2} \sin(t^3)dt$, then $f'(x)=?$

help me. please explain, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x)=(x)'\int_{2}^{x^2} \sin(t^3)dt+x\left(\int_{2}^{x^2} \sin(t^3)dt\right)'$$
$$f'(x)=\int_{2}^{x^2} \sin(t^3)dt+x\left(\int_{2}^{{x^2}} \sin(t^3)dt\right)'$$

$$\left(\int_{2}^{{x^2}} \sin(t^3)dt\right)'=(x^2)'\sin(x^6)=2x\sin(x^6)$$

Comment: $x^6$, maybe...

Comment: not maybe,for sure...

Comment: umm, i still didn't get it. where the 2?(the integral range) isn't it supposed to - by (2) or something :/

Comment: @TactFullbuster The lower limit just changes the value of the integral by an additive constant.  When you differentiate, it disappears.

Comment: how (x^2) got here [(x2)′sin(x6)]

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the antiderivative of the integrand is $S(t)$, such that $S'(t)=\sin(t^3)$. We have

$$f(x)=x(S(x^2)-S(2))$$ and using the chain rule

$$f'(x)=S(x^2)-S(2)+x(2xS'(x^2)-0S'(2))=\int_2^{x^2}\sin(t^3)\,dt+2x^2\sin(x^6).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)= x\int_2^{x^2} \sin(t^3)dt=\int_2^{x^2}x \sin(t^3)dt$$
Using the rule of differentiation under the integral sign,
$$f'(x)=\int_2^{x^2}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x} [x\sin(t^3)]dt~+~x\sin(x^6)\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2)~-~x\sin(8)\dfrac{d}{dx}(2)$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\int_2^{x^2} \sin(t^3)dt~+~x\sin(x^6)(2x)~-~0$$
$$~~~~~~~~=\int_2^{x^2} \sin(t^3)dt~+~2x^2\sin(x^6)$$

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

> **Leibniz Integral Rule (Differentiation under the integral sign):**
>
> Let $f(x, t)$ be a function of $x$ and $t$ such that both $f(x, t)$ and its partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of the $(x, t)$-plane, including $a(x) ≤ t ≤ b(x)$, and $ x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Also suppose that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are both continuous and both have continuous derivatives for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Then, for $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$,
>   $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) dt\right)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,t) dt +f( x, b(x)) \frac{db}{dx}-f( x, a(x)) \frac{da}{dx}$$